# Swift: How to deallocate properties when init throw?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, init, throws, deinit

There is a memory leak with this example code.

The **pointer1** and **pointer2** allocate before Person inits successfully. If the `init` function throws an Error. The `deinit` function will never be executed. So the **pointer1** and **pointer2** will never be released.

```
import XCTest

class Person {

    // case1
    let pointer1: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int> = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1)

    // case2
    let pointer2: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>

    let name: String

    init(name: String) throws {

        // case2
        self.pointer2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1)


        if name == "UnsupportName" {
            throw NSError()
        }
        self.name = name
    }

    deinit {
        pointer1.deallocate()
        pointer2.deallocate()
    }
}

class InterestTests: XCTestCase {

    func testExample() {
        while true {
            _ = try? Person(name: "UnsupportName")
        }
    }

}
```

Sometimes the logic is very complicated. In my real cases. There are a lot of `allocate` and `throws` with `if` and `guard`. Some it's hard to control it.

Is there any way to avoid this memory leak?

Here is a similar question: https://forums.swift.org/t/deinit-and-failable-initializers/1199

Comment: You could call `father.deallocate()` before throwing the error. But I wonder what you are trying to achieve with that “manual memory management.” Why not simply declare `father` as an (possibly implicitly unwrapped) optional, and assign a value when appropriate?

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR. I change the "father" to "aPointer" to reduce confusion.
I understand you. But actually I have a lot of properties like this "aPointer" and a lot of throw logic in init function. It's very hard to manually deallocate in every throws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

```
import XCTest

class Person {

    // case1
    let pointer1: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int> = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1)

    // case2
    let pointer2: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>

    let name: String

    init(name: String) throws {

        // deallocate helper for case1
        var deallocateHelper1: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>? = self.pointer1
        defer {
            deallocateHelper1?.deallocate()
        }

        // case2
        self.pointer2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1)
        var deallocateHelper2: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>? = self.pointer2
        defer {
            deallocateHelper2?.deallocate()
        }

        // case ... 


        if name == "UnsupportName" {
            throw NSError()
        }
        self.name = name

        // In the end. set deallocate helpers to nil
        deallocateHelper1 = nil
        deallocateHelper2 = nil
    }

    deinit {
        pointer1.deallocate()
        pointer2.deallocate()
    }
}

class InterestTests: XCTestCase {

    func testExample() {
        while true {
            _ = try? Person(name: "UnsupportName")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your specific example, the solution is straightforward. Don't allocate any memory until you have resolved all possible failures:

```
class Person {

    let aPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int> // Do not allocate here.
    let name: String

    init(name: String) throws {
        // Validate everything here
        guard name != "UnsupportName" else {
            throw NSError()
        }

        // After this point, no more throwing:

        self.name = name
        // Move the allocation here
        self.aPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate(capacity: 1)
    }

    deinit {
        aPointer.deallocate()
    }
}
```

But the more general solution is to use do/catch like anywhere else you need to manage errors:

```
class Person {

    let aPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    let name: String

    init(name: String) throws {
        do {
            if name == "UnsupportName" {
                throw NSError()
            }

            self.name = name
        } catch let e {
            self.aPointer.deallocate()
            throw e
        }

    }

    deinit {
        aPointer.deallocate()
    }
}
```

I would be tempted to move the `.allocate` inside the `init`, just to make it a bit more visible what's going on. The key point is that you should either allocate all your memory first, before anything can throw (so you know you can deallocate it all), or all after the last throw (so you know you don't have anything to deallocate).

---

Looking at the solution you've added, it's ok, but suggests dangerous logic surrounding it. It would be much better to unwind this to place the allocation into their own objects (which would almost certainly also get rid of the UnsafeMutablePointers; needing a lot of those in a single class is very suspicious).

That said, there are cleaner ways IMO to build the error handling along this path.

```
extension UnsafeMutablePointer {
    static func allocate(capacity: Int, withCleanup cleanup: inout [() -> Void]) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Pointee> {
        let result = allocate(capacity: capacity)
        result.addTo(cleanup: &cleanup)
        return result
    }

    func addTo(cleanup: inout [() -> Void]) {
        cleanup.append { self.deallocate() }
    }
}
```

This lets UnsafeMutablePointers append cleanup information into an array, rather than creating a lot of `defer` blocks, which raises the risk of missing one during cleanup.

With that, your init looks like:

```
init(name: String) throws {
    var errorCleanup: [() -> Void] = []
    defer { for cleanup in errorCleanup { cleanup() } }

    // deallocate helper for case1
    pointer1.addTo(cleanup: &errorCleanup)

    // case2
    self.pointer2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1, withCleanup: &errorCleanup)

    // case ...


    if name == "UnsupportName" {
        throw NSError()
    }
    self.name = name

    // In the end. set deallocate helpers to nil
    errorCleanup.removeAll()
}
```

Of course that setups the danger of calling `allocate(capacity:)` rather than `allocate(capacity:withCleanup:)`. So you could fix that by wrapping it into another type; a reference type that automatically deallocates itself.

```
class SharedPointer<Pointee> {
    let ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Pointee>
    static func allocate(capacity: Int) -> SharedPointer {
        return .init(pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate(capacity: capacity))
    }
    init(pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Pointee>) {
        self.ptr = pointer
    }
    deinit {
        ptr.deallocate()
    }
}
```

With that, this becomes (no deinit required):

```
class Person {

    // case1
    let pointer1 = SharedPointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1)

    // case2
    let pointer2: SharedPointer<Int>

    let name: String

    init(name: String) throws {

        // case2
        self.pointer2 = SharedPointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1)

        if name == "UnsupportName" {
            throw NSError()
        }
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

You'd probably want to write various helpers for dealing with `.ptr`.

Of course this might lead you to build specific versions of SharedPointer to deal with each kind of thing (like "father" rather than "int"). If you continue down that road, you'll find the UnsafeMutablePointers evaporate, and the problem goes away. But you don't have to go that far, and SharedPointer will do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But some times the logic is very complicated. In my cases. There are a lot of `allocate` and `throws` with `if` and `guard`. Some it's hard to control it.

Comment: Then I would strongly recommend redesigning to split up the allocations and place them into their own types that are owned by this one. This is a classic problem that C++ has dealt with for many years, and the general solution is RAII. Do not allow intermixing of logic and allocation. Redesign to separate them into their own pieces. If there are situations where different things are allocated depending on the situation, what you have discovered is a separate type to hold that.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution. Thanks, @Rob Napier. 
Acutally in my cases. There is no only `UnsafePointer`s but also some manually `allocate` and `deallocate` for [libffi](https://github.com/libffi/libffi). [My real project](https://github.com/623637646/SwiftHook/blob/master/SwiftHook/Classes/HookContext.swift#L203) It's hard to wrap all to  `SharedPointer`s. 
However thanks for your good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    let pointer1: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>
    let pointer2: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>

    init(name: String) throws {
        var pointers: [UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>] = []
        do {
            let pointer1 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1)
            pointers.append(pointer1)
            let pointer2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1)
            pointers.append(pointer2)
            if name == "Unsupported Name" {
                throw NSError()
            }
            self.pointer1 = pointer1
            self.pointer2 = pointer2
            self.name = name
        } catch {
            pointers.forEach { $0.deallocate() }
            throw error
        }
    }

    deinit {
        pointer1.deallocate()
        pointer2.deallocate()
    }
}
```